# Running Jython scripts in Eclipse / repeat workspace set-ups

Tags: eclipse, jython, pydev, buildout, aptana

I have created a bunch of Python scripts which I use to set-up Eclipse workspace settings and import Python projects from Buildout configuration tool:

http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/collective.eclipsescripts/trunk/README.txt

(the script scans certain folders, imports all Python egg projects to workspace and sets up some settings)

I have been using these scripts with Aptana Studio 2.0 + Eclipse Monkey + PythonMonkey combo.

However, looks like EclipseMonkey project has been discontinued. What would the modern recommended way to use Jython to run a script within Eclipse run-time context for scripting tasks like this?

Target environment: Aptana Studio 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a real replacement for it... PyDev does have Jython scripting, but it only provides the hooks for what happens in the editor (see: http://pydev.org/manual_articles_scripting.html).

PyDev could in theory be improved to give you more hooks, as it does provide an internal Jython that can access the Eclipse internals -- you may even start an internal interpreter to probe it (Ctrl+Alt+Enter with option to use Eclipse internal Jython), but there are no plans to actually improve it right now (and the current internal Jython is still in version 2.1).

Comment: Any tips where I should start poking in PyDev if I want to copy hooks from PythonMonkey to PyDev directly?

Comment: Probably in the scripting engine. See: org.python.pydev.editor.scripting.PyEditScripting (which is currently the only place where the hooks are available).

Answer (score 0):

Another option to try is to run your python scripts through the Aptana Ruble support in a custom ruble of your own. We support running shell scripts, or inline ruby under JRuby. So you could hook up commands that would launch the python script as a shell script.

If the scripts actually call into Java code through Jython, then that won't really be feasible. In that case, I guess your option would be to port them to ruby, since the commands in Rubles get run under JRuby with full access to the eclipse plugins/Java APIs.

See http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Ruble+Specification and http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Ruble+Cookbook

Comment: I am a Python guy. My friends would crucifix me if I suddenly start writing Ruby for Python project :(